# question about when we use a and when we use an

Tags: sentence-construction

The patient had been waiting in the emergency room for almost an hour before a doctor finally treated her.

(an) goes with a,e,i,o,u

(a) goes with the other letters

why do we use an hour ? instead  of a ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the *h* in the word [**hour**](https://forvo.com/word/hour/#en) (click on the link if you want to hear how native speakers pronounce it) is silent. In other words, it's not pronounced. What you're effectively saying is *our*. And since *our* begins with a vowel, you need to precede it with an *an*.

Comment: Srsly? Why exactly couldn't you find a question this one's a duplicate of? You darn well know there is one (if not twenty).